# Getting error while transferring Data/response from HTTP to UDP protocol through Axis2 webservice in WSO2 ESB

Tags: udp, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

I am new to WSO2 ESB and stuck with one problem of **Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI**.

Actually i want to transfer request/message through UDP transport, for that i have created a Proxy service which transfers request to actual web service through UDP transport.
it seems like :

```
 <proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="example1"
       transports="https http udp"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send>
            <endpoint>
               <address uri="udp://192.168.6.200:3333/services/xyzService?contentType=application/soap+xml">
                  <enableAddressing separateListener="true"/>
               </address>
            </endpoint>
         </send>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full" />
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/WSO2-ws/ABC.wsdl"/>
  </proxy>
```

Other Service get message/request through UDP and transfer to actual WebService.
it seems like:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="example2" transports="udp"
       startOnLoad="true"
       trace="disable">
   <target>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://192.168.6.200:8280/services/abc-demo"/>
      </endpoint>
      <outSequence>
         <log level="full"/>
         <send />
      </outSequence>
   </target>
</proxy>
```

while transferring the Response back to UDP from actual WebService its thrown error like :

```
[2013-11-26 15:06:47,375] ERROR - ProcessPacketTask Error during processing of datagram:
org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPProcessingException: Transport level information does not match with SOAP Message namespace URI
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.BuilderUtil.validateSOAPVersion(BuilderUtil.java:745)
        at org.apache.axis2.builder.SOAPBuilder.processDocument(SOAPBuilder.java:58)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createDocumentElement(TransportUtils.java:180)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:146)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.datagram.ProcessPacketTask.run(ProcessPacketTask.java:63)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

I haven't any idea why it's happened ??
Please suggest me if am doing in wrong way or some configuration are not done properly.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
I look forward to hearing from you soon.

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this sample](http://docs.wso2.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=26838866) which shows switching between UDP and HTTP.

As mentioned in there, you need to add the UDP listener and sender configuration to `<ESB_HOME>/repository/conf/axis2/axis2.xml` file.

```
<transportReceiver name="udp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.udp.UDPListener"/>
<transportSender name="udp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.udp.UDPSender"/>
```

And specify the UDP listening port and content type in the proxy service.

```
<parameter name="transport.udp.port">9999</parameter>
<parameter name="transport.udp.contentType">text/xml</parameter>
```

Comment: i've already configured UDP listener and sender in

`../axis2.xml` file as below:

`<transportReceiver name="udp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.udp.UDPListener" >
  <parameter name="transport.udp.port">3333</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.udp.contentType">application/soap+xml</parameter>
  <parameter name="transport.udp.maxPacketSize">4096</parameter>
 </transportReceiver>

<transportSender name="udp" class="org.apache.axis2.transport.udp.UDPSender"/>`

I m face the error while getting response back from Webservice to UDP.
Please provide some sample code or guidance.